# Selecting questions with zero or more votes

Tags: support, downvotes, filtering

I try to filter interesting recent questions with the following [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=votes%3A0%2B%20%20is%3Aquestion%20intags%3Amine).

This results in the following search box contents:

```
  votes:0+  is:question intags:mine
```

Why do I also get questions with a negative total of votes?

Putting it the other way round:
How can I exclude questions with a negative vote score?

I have tried "score:0+" without success.

Comment: So here's the thing I have not figured out yet. `votes:1` is `>=1`, `votes:.1` is `<=1`, `votes:.0` is `<=0`, but `votes:0` is only `=0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by gunr2171's approach, the proper solution seems to be

```
votes:0.. is:question intags:mine
```

Comment: Yep, they need to update the help article with this information.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `something:0` will always be `=0`, and I can't find a way to change that.

As a workaround, you can use a large range value

```
votes:0-999 is:question intags:mine
```